# Why is it better to return unmodifiableList from a method where list is created?

Tags: java, collections, java-7

```
 public List<Integer> getInts()
{
    List<Integer> xs = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    xs.add(1);
    // return Collections.unmodifiableList(xs);
    return xs;
}
```

I understand that returning an unmodifiable list will prevent the consumer from adding additional elements to the list reference but apart from that what am I gaining here by wrapping it in an unmodifiable list? I am creating a new list every time the method is invoked.

Comment: What's your source for this supposed standard?

Comment: Who told you that it is better to return an unmodifiable list?

Comment: Nothing, you are gaining nothing. Obviously if you decide that later this creation every time is too slow, you may want to cache the result - in that case you would probably return `Collections.singletonList`. Now if you are already returning an immutable `List`, this change won’t cause unexpected errors where consumers of `getInts` have assumed its mutability. So, long story short, returning an immutable `List` will encourage consumers of your API to be well behaved; whether that is a benefit or not is something only you can decide.

Comment: I personally have never heard of this paradigm. If this is stated somewhere, please include reference.

Comment: @Slaw It came up in a code review

Comment: @Impurity you’ve never heard of safe publishing?

Comment: If I were code reviewing I would say `return List.of(1)` or, with Java < 9, `return Collections.singletonList(1)`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Of course I have, in a multi-threading scenario. I'm not quite sure if you can explicitly state it is the best approach always, which is the implied through the question.

Comment: @BoristheSpider This was just an example, there are multiple elements in the list.

Comment: @Impurity publishing means something subtly different in that context. I would argue that immutability should be preferred unless there is a good reason for mutability - not the other way around.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Fair enough! Thank you for the insight.

Comment: Generally it's good to avoid any undocumented behavior as people will make assumptions. If you return a mutable list, it should be documented, and once it's documented, it can't be changed.

Comment: @Bubletan - if nothing is documented then doesn't it mean that it is mutable?

Comment: @linuxNoob but once they poke it and it is, they can come to rely on the behaviour - so changing it later becomes somewhat trickier than it needs to be.

Comment: @BoristheSpider (and linuxNoob) Right, this is informally known as Hyrum's Law, which basically states that any observable behavior of a system will become depended upon by its users. The application here is that, if it isn't documented, then that doesn't "mean" anything. However, in practice, if what's returned is mutable, callers may eventually rely on it being mutable, resulting in breakage if you change it to be unmodifiable in the future. http://www.hyrumslaw.com/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When an object returns a mutable private field, it is exposed to unwanted/unknown alteration of its internal state by external agents, which violates encapsulation.

The pattern to which you refer, called *safe publishing*, protects against this problem. It can be accomplished by returning either a deep copy, or the field (and any mutable sub-fields) in an immutable wrapper.

In the case of your commented out code:

```
return Collections.unmodifiableList(xs);
```

it is creating a new object, but it just a very thin layer on top of the list and you would barely be able to measure the cpu or memory performance cost of doing it.

You can also:

```
return new ArrayList<>(xs);
```

to make a deep copy (in this case, because `Integer` is immutable).

Comment: Isn't this same as defensive copying?

Comment: @user7 "defensive copying" is what I referred to with "deep copy". There are probably many names for this basic concept.

Comment: @user7 no. A defensive copy is a copy - it is a _type_ of safe publishing. This is another type.

Comment: But here the OP isn't returning a private field. They are creating and building the `List` inside the method (i.e. it's a local variable) then returning it. Should you still use safe publishing just in case it becomes a field at some later date (as @BoristheSpider suggests in the question comments)?

Comment: @Slaw one needs to decide what guarantees an API provides - once an API is public it is public for ever. This is the reason that `Collectors.toList` explicitly does not guarantee mutability, even though it currently returns an `ArrayList`, because if the API guaranteed mutability this could never change. Prefer fewer guarantees.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I got it. This just wraps the list and throws NotSupportedException for writes. thanks

Comment: @BoristheSpider Understood, that makes sense.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Certainly for the Java SE APIs we try to avoid making breaking changes; once it's specified a particular way, it's that way pretty much forever. However, other libraries have other policies. Some libraries are willing to make breaking changes for whatever reasons they want. Other libraries will make breaking changes, but only if they can update all callers at the same time. (Yes, that happens.) In any case, the "never change" policy is a specific policy; it's not universal.

Answer (score 9):

The answer from Bohemian states some good general principles about returning unmodifiable, immutable, or defensively-copied data, in order to preserve encapsulation. This is certainly true if the data is internal to the object, e.g., stored in a field.

However, the OP stated that the returned list is newly created each time the method is called. In this case, why return an unmodifiable list instead of a regular ArrayList? There are reasons, but they're somewhat subtle, and they have less to do with encapsulation that with preserving implementation flexibility.

As a background topic, you need to decide whether this API has any long-term compatibility constraints or policies on it. If you return a mutable list, then it's possible (according to [Hyrum's Law](http://www.hyrumslaw.com/)) that callers will come to depend on its mutability. (Hyrum's Law states essentially that any observable property of a system will eventually be depended upon by users.) Personally I think that mutating a collection that's been returned to you is sloppy programming, but the fact is, people do it. If this were the case, and in the future you were to propose changing the returned list to be unmodifiable, would that be prohibited because it's incompatible and it would break some callers? If you don't care about compatibility (and some projects don't) then maybe it doesn't matter. But if you do, then you should think about returning an unmodifiable list now.

One reason (mentioned by others in comments) is that you might decide not to create a fresh list every time, but you might cache it and return it to several callers. If you do this, it should definitely be made unmodifiable, to prevent one caller from modifying the list and affecting all of them.

Another reason is that different list implementations have different performance and space characteristics. The `Collections.singletonList` and `List.of(x)` implementations store their single element in a field of the List object itself, whereas `ArrayList` stores its elements -- even if there's only one -- in a separate array object. The small list implementations can save considerable space 
compared to `ArrayList`, if you're creating a lot of them. Returning an unmodifiable wrapper around an `ArrayList` will ease compatibility concerns if you want to switch to a singleton list or the Java 9 unmodifiable list implementations in the future.

You might also want to add some adaptive behavior to the method, e.g., depending on the number of elements in the returned list. For example,

```
if (count == 0) {
    return Collections.emptyList(); // eventually, List.of()
} else if (count == 1) {
    return Collections.singletonList(i); // eventually, List.of(i)
} else {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    // populate list
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(list);
}
```

If you don't wrap the ArrayList in an unmodifiable wrapper, callers will be exposed to odd differences in behavior, such as the list sometimes being modifiable and sometimes not. If possible, it's best to provide uniform behavior in all cases, thereby preserving implementation flexibility for future changes.

Comment: it's very difficult not to agree with someone that wrote code that I use for nearly 2 years now in production and it feeds my family indirectly. I love your reasonings, thank you!

Comment: @StuartMarks we have multiple permission `if ` checks before adding elements to the list and it could be the case that not all permissions checks are passed. We could cache the permission object along with the the object to be added to the list but it just seems like extra work to me at this point.  I suppose I need a little more functional understanding of how this method will be invoked. Thanks for the detailed explanation though.